# Javascript error: permission denied Highcharts IE8 jQuery AJAX

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-8, highcharts

I'm getting this error in IE8: `Access is denied. highcharts.src.js, line 5122 character 4`.  This error appeared after upgrading Highcharts to version 3.0.6 from version 2.  The context of the error may be the cause: I'm loading some html with inline scripts using jQuery's `html()` method using source from a `$.ajax` call.  However, if anyone has a simpler solution I'd like to hear it because modifying this behavior would be fairly time consuming and it works fine in newer browsers and Highcharts 3.0.5.

```
// The only way to make IE6 and IE7 print is to use a global namespace. However,
// with IE8 the only way to make the dynamic shapes visible in screen and print mode
// seems to be to add the xmlns attribute and the behaviour style inline.
if (!doc.namespaces.hcv) {

    doc.namespaces.add('hcv', 'urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml');

    // Setup default CSS (#2153) 
    // Error occurs on following line
    (doc.styleSheets.length ? doc.styleSheets[0] : doc.createStyleSheet()).cssText +=
        'hcv\\:fill, hcv\\:path, hcv\\:shape, hcv\\:stroke' +
        '{ behavior:url(#default#VML); display: inline-block; } ';

}
```

**Update**: I commented out lines 5122-5124 and everything seems to be working fine... this probably causes bad things to happen though so use at your own risk.   I'm not comfortable doing this in production.

Comment: can you post those lines?

Comment: Which version of jquery do you have?

Comment: @SebastianBochan 1.8.3.  Let me try upgrading.

Comment: So it should work, can you supply live demo or reporduced example in jsfiddle?

Comment: @MikeHometchko Which lines do you want me to post?  I already added the lines where the error occurs.

Comment: @SebastianBochan It would be difficult to create a jsfiddle since it requires server-side communication, and a live demo is not an option unfortunately.  I can post more code snippets though.

Comment: @AlexMA oh those are from highcharts.src.js?  Sorry it's just not very clear (at least to me)

Comment: @SebastianBochan Hey, it worked gloriously with jQuery 1.10.2 (after adding the jquery migrate plugin).  If you add your answer as "try upgrading jquery" I will give you answer credit.  Thanks!!

Comment: Ok I did it, good luck ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try to update to the newest jquery relase.